# Visual Studio 2010 crashes

Tags: asp.net, syncfusion

I've been running Visual Studio 2010, when i drag and drop the "GridGroupingControl" my VS crash.

```
Here is the Problemsignatur:
 Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH
 Problemsignatur 01:    devenv.exe
 Problemsignatur 02:    10.0.40219.1
 Problemsignatur 03:    4d5f2a73
 Problemsignatur 04:    KERNELBASE.dll
 Problemsignatur 05:    6.1.7601.17651
 Problemsignatur 06:    4e211319
 Problemsignatur 07:    80042b8c
 Problemsignatur 08:    0000b9bc
 Betriebsystemversion:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
 Gebietsschema-ID:    1031
```

I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise (x64). can anyone help!

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed more about the issue with “GridGroupingControl” and we suspect the issue may be with VS2010 since the issue is not reproduced in any other packages. We have already posted this issue in the forum with the crashed dump file as msdn request. Please refer this [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/671773/visual-studio-gets-crashed-on-dragging-and-dropping-custom-control-from-toolbox-to-designer-page)

We are waiting for the update from msdn. We will get back to you once we get update from msdn.

Please let me know if you have any other questions or concerns.